# Getting Import error after installing packages through conda

Tags: apt, python, pip, anaconda, conda

I just installed `pandas`, `BeautifulSoup4`, `Jinja2` alongside `conda` distribution, but I'm not able to import any of the packages except `numpy` and others which come pre-installed with `conda`.

Where am I doing this wrong?

Here is a screenshot of my terminal window, where you can see the `ImportError and ModuleNotFoundError` in Python 2 and 3 respectively. I didn't try `pip` because I thought it might make things worse by breaking something.

[image: screenshot of my terminal window]

Comment: Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: If you need global-level packages, just use  `python(3) -m pip install <packages>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to import those packages from **native** installed python/python3 environments (unless you've installed them using `pip`/`pip3`). Anaconda uses **virtual environments** (the default one is called **base**).

You have to *activate* **base** virtual environment and use **its** **python** in order to install additional packages using `pip`/`pip3` or import Anaconda's preinstalled packages :

```
conda activate base
python
>>> import pandas
>>> exit()
conda deactivate
```

OR

```
conda activate base
python3
>>> import pandas
>>> exit()
conda deactivate
```

You can check installed packages inside **base** virtual environment using :

```
conda activate base
pip list
pip3 list
conda deactivate
```

If u have several conda environment (other than **base**), you can list them using :

```
conda env list
```

Finally, you can run your scripts using :

```
conda activate env_name # env_name is probably base in your case
python script.py
conda deactivate
```

OR

```
conda activate env_name
python3 script.py
conda deactivate
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but I'm not able to `import pandas` in `(base) env` in python3, I just checked, it's working when using python

Comment: you've created a python2 conda environment (done by default), if you want to create a python3 env, run `conda create -n mypython3env python=3`

Comment: Now, I get it. Thanks

Comment: more details here : https://salishsea-meopar-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/work_env/python3_conda_environment.html